# Is there a way of putting the text of a div in another div on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, containers

Is there a simple way of putting the text of a div in another div on click? I did it before with inputs, but I used `.val()`.

```
 <div id="someText"> Hello </div>
 <div id="putHere"> </div>
```

I'm glad for help, Thanks!

Comment: Use `.text()` or `.html()` with `div` as the don't have `value` property which `.val()` uses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery !

Click Event on `div`

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
  $("#someText").on("click", function (){
      $("#putHere").text($(this).text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="someText"> Click Me! </div>
<div id="putHere"> </div>
```

Click Event on `Button`

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
  $("#btn").on("click", function (){
      $("#putHere").text($("#someText").text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="someText"> Hello World! </div>
<div id="putHere"> </div>
<button id="btn">Click ME !</button>
```

Pure JS

Click Event on `button`

```js
document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("putHere").innerHTML =  document.getElementById("someText").innerHTML;
};
```

```html
<div id="someText">Hello World!</div>
<div id="putHere"></div>
<button id="btn">Click ME !</button>
```

Click Event on `div`

```js
document.getElementById("someText").onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("putHere").innerHTML =  document.getElementById("someText").innerHTML;
};
```

```html
<div id="someText">Click Me!</div>
<div id="putHere"></div>
```

Comment: Can I use instead of `$("#button")`  `$("#someText")` ?

Comment: yes, i can use that too.. In your question you asked when u click on button.. so i added button event

Comment: Thank you :) Best, because it shows JS & jQuery if someone is passing by

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for `.text()`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#click,#div2').on('click',function() {
   $('#div2').text($('#div1').text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">Foo</div>
<div id="div2">Bar</div>

<button id="click">Click</button>
```

Comment: I agree: but this is tagged as jQuery so made that assumption.

Comment: Ah, in that case, fair assumption. I had missed that.

Comment: Can I use  `$("#div1")` instead of `$("#click")` ? Because I don't really need a button on my program

Comment: You can use the event on any clickable element. Just attach it to a different reference ID e.g. another `div` -> `$('#div2').on('click',function() { // ... `. Added above.

Answer (score 2):

This is a pure `Javascript` solution if you are interested :

```js
document.getElementById('someText').onclick = function(){
  document.getElementById('putHere').textContent = document.getElementById('someText').textContent;
};
```

```html
<div style='background:red' id="someText"> Hello </div>
<div style='background:blue' id="putHere"> </div>
```

**Update:** Removed Button since the OP didn't need one. Now click on the red div and blue div will be populated

Comment: Thank you but I'm looking a bit for jQuery :)

Comment: @LorisVonlanthen sure.. No problem

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```js
$('#putHere').text($('#someText').text());
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("button").click(function()  {
  $("#putHere").html($("#someText").text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="someText"> Hello </div>
<div id="putHere"> </div>
<button>Click</button>
```